# Windows Anaconda PyQwt Installation / Gohkle Binary

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda

I am trying to install PyQwt on Anaconda on Windows.  It appears the [Gohkle binary distribution](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) is the best way to go about it, but I get an error that the "copy of PyQwt has been built against Python-2.7.x which doesn't seem to be installed."

I have my main python and /Scripts directory in my PATH - I don't have any trouble running pip or conda installs.  Do these binaries look for a specific environment variable that I (evidently) have missing?

Comment: Try download the PyQwt-5.2.1 and PyQt4‑4.10.4 installers fitting your Anaconda Python environment, extract the files from the installers using 7zip, and copy the extracted files to the appropriate places in the Anaconda virtual environment...

Comment: I think that worked.  Want to move your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users:

1. uninstall pyqt4 on dir anaconda
2. install pyqt4  this version
   on anaconda dir PyQt4.Qwt5-5.2.1.win32-py27.exe
3. install pyqwt5.2.0-python2.6-pyqt4.5.4-numpy1.3.0-1.exe

Important  is for python2.6. you need to put the correct directory for installation on anaconda.